# How to authenticate SVN Repository through API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are developing a replica of Jenkins and we have a need to authenticate SVN & GIT repository URLs. I see Jenkins is able to do it through allowing the user to have credentials created(POST) and validated through(GET) a  call. However, I am unable to validate the SVN/GIT repo without the jobname. 
I am able to fetch the global credentials added to Jenkins. But they are only retrieved for job basis. So if I want to see the list of credentials of a particular job, I can do it using the following JSON.

http://${JENKINS_URL&PORT}/job/${JOB_NAME}/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$ModuleLocation/fillCredentialsIdItems

But I would like to fetch the credentials without depending on the job name. Please let me know if I have to provide any more information. Any help is much appreciated.